# Counting multiple columns & groups from one UNION ALL query

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to get counts of items in multiple columns in a `union all`-ed query.

I have a MySQL database of trips taken, with location data for origin and destination for each trip. The columns are as such:

| o_continent | o_country | o_state | o_city | d_continent | d_country | d_state | d_city | tripdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| North America | United States | California | San Diego | North America | United States | Arizona | Phoenix | 2020-10-01 |
| North America | United States | California | Los Angeles | North America | United States | California | Santa Rosa | 2020-04-03 |
| North America | United States | California | Los Angeles | North America | United States | Washington | Spokane | 2020-03-01 |
| North America | United States | Oregon | Portland | North America | Canada | Alberta | Calgary | 2020-01-22 |
| North America | Canada | Alberta | Edmonton | North America | United States | California | Los Angeles | 2020-04-01 |

I am merging the origins and the destinations using `UNION ALL`, as such:

```
SELECT o__continent as continent, o__country as country, o__state_name as state, o__city_name as city, o_ AS code
FROM db.trips
WHERE year(tripdate) = 2020
UNION ALL
SELECT d__continent as continent, d__country as country, d__state_name as state, d__city_name as city, d_ AS code
FROM db.trips
WHERE year(tripdate) = 2020
```

This produces a table that looks like this:

| continent | country | state | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| North America | Canada | Alberta | Calgary |
| North America | Canada | Alberta | Edmonton |
| North America | United States | Arizona | Phoenix |
| North America | United States | California | Los Angeles |
| North America | United States | California | Los Angeles |
| North America | United States | California | Los Angeles |
| North America | United States | California | San Diego |
| North America | United States | California | Santa Rosa |
| North America | United States | Oregon | Portland |
| North America | United States | Washington | Spokane |

I am seeking out how I might be able to group these together (obviously traditionally you would use `GROUP BY continent, country, state, city`), but also to count the instances of each column in separate columns. The ideal final result would look something like this (*note:* the `Los Angeles` entries are grouped):

| continent | country | state | city | continent_count | country_count | state_count | city_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| North America | Canada | Alberta | Calgary | 10 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| North America | Canada | Alberta | Edmonton | 10 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| North America | United States | Arizona | Phoenix | 10 | 8 | 1 | 1 |
| North America | United States | California | Los Angeles | 10 | 8 | 5 | 3 |
| North America | United States | California | San Diego | 10 | 8 | 5 | 1 |
| North America | United States | California | Santa Rosa | 10 | 8 | 5 | 1 |
| North America | United States | Oregon | Portland | 10 | 8 | 1 | 1 |
| North America | United States | Washington | Spokane | 10 | 8 | 1 | 1 |

I have been sifting for several days through other potential answers to this question on StackOverflow with little luck. Ideally I would not query the `db.trips` database over and over, as it is large. Is there a way to do this without losing too much efficiency?

Any help offered is most kindly and greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY column)`. PS *`WHERE year(tripdate) = 2020`* - there is no `tripdate` column in your data...

Comment: Regrettably I am seeking a solution for MySQL 5.7, so I can not use the `OVER` function. I also omitted the `tripdate` from my example; it is now posted.

Comment: TLDRjust the comments and it looked like an analytic would work: so..."Any help offered is most kindly and greatly appreciated" 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql shows you how to simulate it using variables and a cross join or better a set statement I believe .  Several options there...

Comment: Or maybe: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94545/calculate-row-value-based-on-previous-and-actual-row-values as the above is for row_number...

Comment: What does it mean that the city_count is lower than the continent_count?

Comment: You say db.trips is large - how big is it? 1,000s, 100,000s or 10,000,000s rows? Saying a table is large means nothing when people have different interpretations. Avoid unnecessary coercion like `WHERE year(tripdate) = 2020` when it can be just as easily written as `WHERE tripdate BETWEEN '2020-01-01` AND '2020-12-31' which can use indices and does not require a function call for every row.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you said you are stuck on MySQL 5.7, your best bet is going to be a normal GROUP BY and then post processing the counts in your programming language of choice -

```sql
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS l_count
FROM (
(
    SELECT o_continent as continent, o_country as country, o_state as state, o_city as city
    FROM trips
    WHERE tripdate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
 ) UNION ALL (
    SELECT d_continent as continent, d_country as country, d_state as state, d_city as city
    FROM trips
    WHERE tripdate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
)
) `locations`
GROUP BY continent, country, state, city
ORDER BY continent ASC, country ASC, state ASC, city ASC;
```

But if you want to build the final result set in SQL there are a few different approaches and this performed best with my test dataset -

```sql
SELECT `locations`.*,
    `continents`.`count` AS continent_count,
    `countries`.`count` AS country_count,
    `states`.`count` AS state_count,
    COUNT(*) AS city_count
FROM (
(
    SELECT o_continent as continent, o_country as country, o_state as state, o_city as city
    FROM trips
    WHERE tripdate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
 ) UNION ALL (
    SELECT d_continent as continent, d_country as country, d_state as state, d_city as city
    FROM trips
    WHERE tripdate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
)
) `locations`
INNER JOIN (
    -- DERIVED TABLE FOR COUNT OF CONTINENTS
    SELECT continent, SUM(cnt) AS `count` FROM (
        SELECT o_continent AS continent, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM trips WHERE tripdate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31' GROUP BY continent
        UNION ALL
        SELECT d_continent AS continent, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM trips WHERE tripdate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31' GROUP BY continent
    ) tmp
    GROUP BY continent
) `continents` ON `locations`.`continent` = `continents`.`continent`

INNER JOIN (
    -- DERIVED TABLE FOR COUNT OF COUNTRIES
    SELECT country, SUM(cnt) AS `count` FROM (
        SELECT o_country AS country, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM trips WHERE tripdate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31' GROUP BY country
        UNION ALL
        SELECT d_country AS country, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM trips WHERE tripdate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31' GROUP BY country
    ) tmp
    GROUP BY country
) `countries` ON `locations`.`country` = `countries`.`country`

INNER JOIN (
    -- DERIVED TABLE FOR COUNT OF STATES
    SELECT state, SUM(cnt) AS `count` FROM (
        SELECT o_state AS state, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM trips WHERE tripdate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31' GROUP BY state
        UNION ALL
        SELECT d_state AS state, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM trips WHERE tripdate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31' GROUP BY state
    ) tmp
    GROUP BY state
) `states` ON `locations`.`state` = `states`.`state`

GROUP BY `locations`.`continent`, `locations`.`country`, `locations`.`state`, `locations`.`city`
ORDER BY `locations`.`continent` ASC, `locations`.`country` ASC, `locations`.`state` ASC, `locations`.`city` ASC;
```

If you are running MySQL > 8.0 then using window functions is definitely the easiest and most performant solution -

```sql
SELECT *,
    SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY continent) AS continent_count,
    SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY country) AS country_count,
    SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY state) AS state_count,
    COUNT(*) AS city_count
FROM (
(
    SELECT o_continent as continent, o_country as country, o_state as state, o_city as city
    FROM trips
    WHERE tripdate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
 ) UNION ALL (
    SELECT d_continent as continent, d_country as country, d_state as state, d_city as city
    FROM trips
    WHERE tripdate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
)
) `locations`
GROUP BY continent, country, state, city
ORDER BY continent ASC, country ASC, state ASC, city ASC;
```